# How to use Bezier-Curve Animation in view?

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design, bezier

I am curious to build this type of [login screen](https://dribbble.com/shots/2145451--01-Compact-Login).

[image]
 I tried to build this but only thing i could achieve was RevealEffect.

**My Code**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.fab:
            showRegisterView();
            break;
        case R.id.register_cross:
            hideRegisterView();
            break;
            }
        }

private void showRegisterView() {
    CommonMethods.getInstance().hideSoftKeyboard(mContext,rootView);
    registerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mFab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

    registerView.post(showAnimationRunnable);
}
    /**
    Runnable to show animation, Here Register scren will be shown after animation
    */

private final Runnable showAnimationRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // get the center for the clipping circle
        int cx = registerView.getRight() + registerView.getLeft();
        int cy = registerView.getTop();

        // get the final radius for the clipping circle
        float finalRadius = Math.max(registerView.getWidth(), registerView.getHeight());

        // create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
        Animator anim =
                    null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(registerView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);
            }
            anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                }
            });
            // make the view visible and start the animation
            anim.start();
        }
    };

    /**
    Hide Register View and show Login view
    */
    private void hideRegisterView(){
        // get the center for the clipping circle
        int cx = registerView.getBottom();
        int cy = registerView.getTop();

        // get the final radius for the clipping circle
        float initialRadius = Math.max(registerView.getWidth(), registerView.getHeight());


        // create the animation (the final radius is zero)
        Animator anim =
                null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(registerView, cx, cy, initialRadius, 0);
        }

        // make the view invisible when the animation is done
        anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                registerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                loginView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mFab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            }
        });
        anim.setInterpolator(new FastOutSlowInInterpolator());
        // start the animation
        anim.start();
    }
```

But this is not enough to get the whole functionality. I need to move FAB and have to show cross icon. I have no idea how to achieve this.
I am new to Animation part in Android.

I read about [Curved Motion](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html) but having no idea how to implement in my code.

Please help using code.

Comment: can you simplify this question to a single problem you want to solve, with an [mvce](/help/mcve) specifically for that problem, instead of this "many, many aspects all covered in the same code" example to mimic someone else's full UI/UX? (Did you ask them whether you could look at their code? What did they say?)